# Why doesn't const range based for use const_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, constants, auto

If I only want to expose a const iterator to by object:

```
class MyList
{
  public:
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
  private:
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
};
```

it seems I should be able to use a const version of the range based for:

```
MyList list;
...
for(const auto & value : list)
{
}
```

The compiler complains that `begin` and `end` are private. Why doesn't it use the `const_iterator` versions?

Comment: `template <class T> T const& as_const(T const& t) { return t; }`....`for (auto& value : as_const(list)) ...`

Comment: This is a pretty user-unfriendly design since you can no longer do `MyList list; list.begin();`. Consider renaming the private non-const versions to something else.

Comment: I agree, but it's only user-unfriendly because the compiler refuses to find the const version of begin/end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overload resolution is done before access-checking, to avoid magically breaking code just by changing access-specifiers.

What happens to the expression afterwards (its type) is disregarded for that. If needed, the compiler will try to find a valid and unambiguous conversion-sequence afterwards instead.

Thus, the `begin` and `end` for a non-`const`-object are selected, and then the compiler stumbles over that big `private`-sign.

Comment: But then why can't the compiler see the `const auto &` and realize that it should use the `const_iterator` version (which will happen to be public)?

Comment: The compiler never does overload-resolution based on where you use the result. It tries to find a valid conversion sequence afterwards instead.

Comment: Occasionally the result does go back to overload resolution (`static_cast`ing the name of an overloaded function, for instance), but this isn't one of those few contexts, and in any event access control happens after overload resolution.